# Alternative to IndentingXMLStreamWriter.java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, indentation

Is their an alternative to IndentingXMLStreamWriter.java i've always had some sort of issue at some point in which i am unable to compile though it goes away after a while. So I was wondering if their was an alternate way to indent manually parsed XML files

though the error message is slightly differnt when it is compiled as part of a netbeans module... the paths are alterered with ~ for anyone thats wondering =p

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\MasterDeckXMLImporterExporter.java:5: package com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.output does not exist
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter;
Note: Attempting to workaround 6512707
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: [javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement, javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\MasterDeckXMLImporterExporter.java:5: package com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.output does not exist
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter;

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\MasterDeckXMLImporterExporter.java:68: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IndentingXMLStreamWriter
location: class com.spectre.util.MasterDeckXMLImporterExporter
            xsw = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(xsw);
2 errors
3 warnings
C:\Program Files\jmonkeyplatform\harness\suite.xml:182: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\jmonkeyplatform\harness\common.xml:206: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Just to be a bit clear on things this would be how i would use stax

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter;

XMLStreamWriter xsw = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("Blah")));
xsw = new IndentingXMLStreamWriter(xsw);
xsw.writeStartDocument();
xsw.writeStartElement("map");
for (Map.Entry<String, Date> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     xsw.writeEmptyElement("entry1");
     xsw.writeAttribute("Name", entry.getKey());
     xsw.writeAttribute("date", sdf.format(entry.getValue()));
 }
 xsw.writeEndElement();
 xsw.writeEndDocument();
 xsw.close();
```

Comment: What did you end up doing? I've run into this exact issue - specifically trying to compile with maven using the IndentingXMLStreamWriter. I'd like to adopt the JDK classes, but I'm not willing to reparse the output just to use the Transformer class. So it looks like I might end up punting and just use the XPP3 serializer like I've done in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Saxon. In the s9api interface, you can do something like

```
Processor p = new Processor();
Serializer s = p.newSerializer(System.out);
s.setOutputProperty(Property.INDENT, "yes");
XMLStreamWriter w = s.getXMLStreamWriter();
```

and then you have an indenting serializer that implements the XMLStreamWriter interface, with many more formatting options available if you want to play with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse your XML to an instance of org.w3c.Document (e.g. using DocumentBuilderFactory), you could try the following.

Using Apache Xerces:

```
Document doc = ...;
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
format.setIndenting(true);
format.setIndent(2);
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(out, format);
serializer.serialize(doc);
```

Or using the standard TransformerFactory:

```
Document doc = ...;
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(out));
```

Comment: Note that the `XMLSerializer` class is no longer available in the Xerces2 package. You will have to use the JAX-P standard (i.e. the `Transformer`) version if you are using vanilla JDK 1.6, apache XML, or Xerces2.